# Yii CMenu & CSS

Tags: css, yii

I am having problems having my CSS applied when a menu item links to a specific record.

Take the simple menu below, the CSS as defined in Menu works just fine for 'Account' but when I click on 'My Account' it doesn't.

```
<div id="Menu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Account', 'url'=>array('/account/view'),  
                // CSS works fine
        array('label'=>'My Account', 'url'=>array('/account/view/id/'.Yii::app()->user->id), 
                // CSS applied to active link does not work
            ),
        )); 
    ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Menu ul li.active a {
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: can you show the rendered output? are there any global rules overriding this? did you firebug it to see what's being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<div id="Menu">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Account', 'url'=>array('/account/view'),  
                // CSS works fine
        array(
            'label'=>'My Account',
            'url'=>array('/account/view/id/'.Yii::app()->user->id), 
            'active'=>($this->getId() == 'account' && $this->getAction()->getId() == 'view' && isset($_GET['id'])))
                // you have to set manually the rule for "active"
            ),
        )); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Also you should correct your Url rules so you can create URLs properly like this:

```php
'url'=>array('account/view', 'id'=>Yii::app()->user->id)
```

To obtain the correct url from this you should create URL rule in config file like this:

```php
'rules'=>array(
    ....
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ....
),
```

Comment: Johnatan thanks for the help here and the additional URL tips.  In this  menu I have links to multiple views from the same controller.  Using your code all links are showing active at the same time now.  So changing to 'active'=>$this->action->id=='view'), changing 'view' to each view works.